# Is it possible to dynamically set variables in ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables, dynamic, global-variables, calabash

I am wondering if it is possible, given that these global variables exist and are accessed by other functions, to tell a function to use one variable or another without re-writing huge chunks of code. I have to use global variables because of my limitations with calabash passing variables around (correct me if I'm wrong). I want to be able to call one function that can grab information and stuff it into one of several global variables. Something hopefully like this:

```
def add_five(my_var)

   if my_var == "my_cats"
      use $my_cats for my_var_nickname
   elsif my_var == "my_dogs"
      use $my_dogs for my_var_nickname
   elsif my_var == "my_birds"
      use $my_birds for my_var_nickname
   end

   my_var_nickname = my_var_nickname + 5
end

$my_cats = 2
$my_dogs = 3
$my_birds = 3

add_five("my_cats")

$my_cats = 7
$my_dogs = 3
$my_birds = 3
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could write something like `b = ((stuffy == "foo") ? $A : $B)` and then use `b`, but you should try to avoid using global variables.

Comment: Using globals (`$`) like that has significant code smell.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have much choice when using calabash. I need a way to record and communicate data back and forth between test steps.

Comment: Try reading this http://ryanverner.com/post/33837637667/ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 1):

I second the point that using global variables has a foul smell to it...

Anyway, you could try using a [hash](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_hashes.htm):

```
$animal_counts = {}
def add_five(animal_type)
  $animal_counts[animal_type] += 5
end

$animal_counts[:cats]  = 2
$animal_counts[:dogs]  = 3
$animal_counts[:birds] = 3

add_five(:cats)

$animal_counts[:cats]  # => 7
$animal_counts[:dogs]  # => 3
$animal_counts[:birds] # => 3
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm that is interesting. In my actual case, the globals are already hashes themselves... I'll have to look into this one more.

Answer (score 0):

```
def record_as(stuff)
   variable_to_use = if stuff == "foo"
      $variableA
   elsif stuff == "bar"
      $variableB
   end

   #do stuff with variable_to_use
end
```

Comment: Will that save it back in the original variable or is that just making a copy of it to use in that function?

Comment: This creates a new reference to the variable, so editing the new reference will reflect on the global

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the questions for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I tried it, and the information never made it back out to the global variable. It could have something to do with the fact that it's in the middle of a calabash step too though.

Comment: We don't use `variableA` for variable names in Ruby by convention, whether they're global or not. Instead, use snake_case, `variable_a`.

Answer (score 0):

For simple use
In your ruby step file define a variable like this

```
$global_memory=""
```

In your calabash step which is ok to be in another ruby step file. 
Read some text from query and store it on that variable in run time.

```
Then I should memorize delivery time
```

Which define in ruby step file like this

```
Then /^I should memorize delivery time$/ do
  srctext=query("label marked:'lblOrderTime'",:text).first
  srctext=srctext.to_s
  $global_memory.replace(srctext)
end
```

Later in the scenario you can recall that value and use it like this

```
Then I should see order dispatch time same as in checkout screen and receipt screen
```

Which define in ruby step file like this

```
Then /^I should see order dispatch time same as in checkout screen and receipt screen$/ do |arg|
  datetext=$global_memory
    result = query("webView css:'SPAN' index:5").first["textContent"].include? "#{datetext}"
    unless result
      textFound = query("webView css:'TABLE' index:0").first["textContent"]
      screenshot_and_raise "time  #{datetext} not found instead #{textFound} is found"
    end 
end
```

Further you can use Hash (Key value pairs) to store many variable at same time and retrieve them.